# Help understanding matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I'm stuck on this one task where I should solve the matrix system, but I'm stuck on this part:

https://gyazo.com/fc02fbbe898b586d9901164a6173d766

What I don't understand is how to eliminate 1 2 0 -6 to 1 0 0 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sum to the first row the second row multiplied by $-2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite the system in the normal form:

$\begin{array}{lcl} 
x+2y+0z & = & -6 \\ 
0x+y+0z & = & -3 \\
0x+0y+z & = & 1 
 \end{array} \rightarrow 
\begin{array}{lcl} 
1x + 2*(-3)+0z & = & -6 \\ 
0x+y+0z & = & -3 \\
0x+0y+1z & = & 1 
 \end{array} \rightarrow 
\begin{array}{lcl} 
1x + 0y +0z & = & 0 \\ 
0x+1y+0z & = & -3 \\
0x+0y+1z & = & 1 
 \end{array}$

Hope it is helpful. 
Moreover, plz do the research before asking, and write-right form of the question. The tutorial is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).